# Why can't I migrate this question?

Tags: support

I wanted to migrate this question https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4584/what-are-the-best-quality-bose-speakers-for-conference-calls to http://sound.stackexchange.com but I couldn't.

I can only migrate to Meta Music Fans.

[image: migration]

I know now it was not a good question for them either, but I just wanted to know why the functionality did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migration is something that is generally discouraged for beta sites. This is not, as I understand it, an arbitrary rule, but rather one that has evolved from experience with many different betas.

By default, non-mods on beta sites can only migrate to meta of the same site. Sites that have graduated will get a list of pre-approved migration paths that cover the majority of the sites migration needs.

Everything else has to be handled by moderators who can migrate anywhere. However, questions are not migrated lightly. Is it a quality question? Is it really on-topic on the target site? (as opposed to "What would be the closest fit?")